# Multi Screen/Window QT QML C++ application

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am new to QT Quick and QML and I am trying to build a Linux Desktop multi Window application using C++ and QT. I mean application having multiples windows like:

- Slash or Welcome Screen
- Main Dashboard
- User Profile
- Charts and Graphs
- Etc. etc.

I want to have these screens as independent C++ classes and QML files for example:

- Dashboard.cpp
- Dashboard.qml

I am able to build QML files representing these screens but not sure how to map them to a class which will control and communicate with QML and backend. I want to have each QML file represented as C++ Class. And screen stack manager will use these classes to push and pop screens from the screen stack.

I have seen the examples provided by QT but most of the examples are single screen and not explaining how to have multiple screens and how the screen stack is maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Quick Controls 2 StackView control:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html

This control maintains a stack of QML views where the top one is always visible and you can pop and push views with animation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was really helpful. I will use StackView to build the application. But can we access StackView from C++ code to push and pop QML screens, link to example will help. Also is the screen gets destroyed when we pop the screen?

Comment: You can access it from C++ like any other QML object by passing a reference to it from the QML side to the C++ side. Re: memory management, it depends if you push on an already created object or a reference to a Component/QML file. That link to the documentation discussions ownership and memory management concerns.